# Why do my exported video files have no audio?

Tags: video, audio, adobe-premiere

I installed Premiere Elements 10 yesterday, and created a video which consists of a bunch of still images with an audio track. After editing I used the "Share" tab and tried to save the file in various formats.

The MP4 worked but with astoundingly crappy audio quality, even when set for very good quality. (The video file's audio quality is much worse than the original mp3 file used as the audio track.)

The AVI, WMV, and MPEG2 files were silent. No audio at all, although there is an audio track included, it's just silent.

The F4V file has the audio randomly scrambled. It's divided into little snippets no longer than about two seconds, and which are in a random order that has nothing to do with the actual mp3 file. The audio consists of one MP3 file but PE somehow managed to scramble it anyway.

Clearly something about my systems's audio setup is not compatible with PE, but how can I find out what?

I'm running PE on a Windows Vista box. (Skip the jokes, I'm replacing it within a couple of weeks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I ended up being able to do, and this is very stupid, was choose to upload the video to my YouTube channel (privately) and then download a working MP4 from them.